# How to find the center of N vectors if I don't have the dimensions

Tags: vectors

Lets assume that I have a set of lines with 2 numbers per line. Each line corresponds a vector and the first number of each line corresponds its norm while the 2nd corresponds the angle in rads from a specific vector 'X'.

An example is this:

```
//norm, angle (In rads from the vector 'X')
  2.56, 1.51  //Vector A
  14.0, 1.57  //Vector B
  9.57, 0.18  //Vector C
  5.02, 1.27  //Vector D
  4.99, 0.00  //Vector E (This could also be the vector 'X')
```

Now, I need to calculate the norm of the centroid of these 5 vectors as well as the angle of this, from vector 'X' in rads. I need this for a program in python, so a function that already exists and implement this, could also be my answer.

Edit: all angles in rads are between [0, π/2]

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to calculate the norm of the center of these 5 vectors"? You already have the norms, right?

Comment: i have the norms of the 5 vectors and i need to know the norm of their centroid as well as its angle.

Comment: To compute the centroid you'll first need to convert from this norm-angle polar coordinate representation to the traditional Cartesian (x,y) representation. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I actually do have the dimensions on a file if that's what you mean, but i really need to avoid them due to massive overhead and ram occupation of the program if i use them.

Comment: How is there a massive overhead if you're just computing the centre of 5 vectors?

Comment: I wrote a KMeans algorithm program and my file consists of 10 million vectors with 1024 dimensions each. That's over 2 GB file size and pycharm which likes to eat alot of ram goes over 10 GB ram and uses swap file algorithm which also reduces my ssd's lifespan. Also, it takes >10 hours for 30 clusters and max 5 repeats. And that is for one run. I need to run it like 50 times with different parameters.

Comment: Thus, i created a file with the norm and the angle of the vectors of the file (37 MB) and i use cosine similarity instead of euclidean distance (a^2=b^2 + c^2 -2*b*c*cos(angle)). This reduces ram massively (from 10m x 1024 to 10m x 2) as well as execution times from hours to a couple of minutes.

Comment: Can we assume that the "reduced" problem in your Question is 2D? And that the angle ranges [-π, π], or [0, 2π] or something? I don't think the problem is soluble otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, all dimensions are >0 so ranges of angles are [0, π/2] or [0, 1.57]. You can safely assume that vectors consist of 2 dimensions only if thats what you mean.

Comment: I think you lose far too much information this way. The vectors could all be angled in the same direction away from $X$, which gives you one answer, or they could be angled in all different directions, giving you a different answer. The only thing you can tell reliably is the orthogonal projection of the centroid onto $X.$ If you want more than that, I think a better way is to take 10,000 vectors at a time, compute the centroid of each subset; now you have 1000 points, compute the centroid of those points, using weights if the sets aren't all exactly 10,000 vectors each.

Comment: Indeed, i lose alot of information now that you mention it. Maybe I'll stick with euclidean distance instead.Thank you.